# Transforming a mapping matrix

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have a 2-dimensional array of ones and zeros called M where the g rows represent groups and the a columns represent articles. M maps groups and articles. If a given article "art" belongs to group "gr" then we have M[gr,art]=1; if not we have M[gr,art]=0.

Now, I would like to convert M into a square a x a matrix of ones and zeros (call it N) where if an article "art1" is in the same group as article "art2", we have N(art1,art2)=1 and N(art1,art2)=0 otherwise. N is clearly symmetric with 1's in the diagonal.

How do I construct N based on M?

Many thanks for your suggestions - and sorry if this is trivial (still new to python...)!

Comment: showing a concrete example with actual code is always a good idea, much easier to copy-paste that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a boolean matrix `M` like the following:

```
>>> M
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> ngroups, narticles = M.shape
```

and what you want is a matrix of shape `(narticles, narticles)` that represents [co-occurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-occurrence_matrix). That's simply the square of the matrix:

```
>>> np.dot(M, M.T)
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 2]])
```

... except that you don't want counts, so set entries > 0 to 1.

```
>>> N = np.dot(M, M.T)
>>> N[N > 0] = 1
>>> N
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]])
```